# jQuery: create element after paticualr row

Tags: jquery

There are 40 products.

Each row contains 3 products. Now, what I'am looking for is to create a new full width div just below the clicked elements' row.

I fetch data and inserted after the click element but it is inserting after the li, which displaying just right side.

Check the screenshot:

```
<ul class="products">
    <li datarow="row1" id="rows-49" class="post-49 product type-product status-publish hentry instock">
        <a href="http://domain.com/gold/?product=hunter">
            <img width="267" height="267" alt="box1" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" src="http://domain.com/gold/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/box1.jpg">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li datarow="row2" id="rows-136" class="post-136 product type-product status-publish hentry last instock">
        <a href="http://domain.com/gold/?product=hunter2">
            <img width="267" height="267" alt="box1" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" src="http://domain.com/gold/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/box1.jpg">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li datarow="row2" id="rows-44" class="post-44 product type-product status-publish hentry first instock">
        <a href="http://domain.com/gold/?product=ring">
             <img width="267" height="267" alt="SS_Men_01" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" src="http://domain.com/gold/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/SS_Men_01-267x267.jpg">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li datarow="row2" id="rows-137" class="post-137 product type-product status-publish hentry instock">
        <a href="http://domain.com/gold/?product=ring2">
            <img width="267" height="267" alt="SS_Men_01" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" src="http://domain.com/gold/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/SS_Men_01-267x267.jpg">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.products li a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('343');
        var links = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        var cs = jQuery(this).parent().attr('id');
        alert(cs);
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: links,
            beforeSend: function () {
                alert('Yes');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var dd = jQuery(data).find('#content .product').html();
                jQuery('<li class="new-rows"></li>').insertAfter('#' + cs);
                jQuery('.new-rows').html(dd);
            }
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Why not use console.log for debugging rather than alerts?